# Eloquent: Invalid default value with timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-timestamp

Here's my migration schema:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('objects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamp('timestamp1');
        $table->timestamp('timestamp2');
    });
}
```

But when I execute `php artisan migrate`, I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 **Invalid default value for 'timestamp2'** (SQL: create table `objects` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `timestamp1` timestamp not null, `timestamp2` timestamp not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

I must indicate that when I remove one of the 2 `$table->timestamp(...);` lines it works, but it doesn't when there is both. And the `Object.php` model is empty as it can be. Did I make a mistake?

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946136/laravel-eloquent-overwriting-a-custom-timestamp-why), but even though there is no longer errors when I change `timestamp(...)` into `dateTime(...)`, I only want timestamps.

Comment: The create statement works fine for me. What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: There will be only one timestamp col in a table so make it **CHAR** the update the data type of the col.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Timestamps are a little special, they must either be nullable or they must have a default value. So you must choose between `timestamp('timestamp1')->nullable();` or `timestamp('timestamp1')->useCurrent()` or a custom default value like `timestamp('timestamp1')->default(DB::raw('2018-01-01 15:23'))`.

Comment: I think all data types must be either nullable or have a default value.

Comment: That's not true, `VARCHAR` and `INT` for example can be non-nullable and without a default value. You just have to fill the value during insertion.

Comment: WTF Mysql!?  Why can't we just require that a timestamp has to be set on insert like every other column?  What a headache.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multiple-timestamps-in-one-table) solution on laracasts:

`nullableTimestamps()` are only for default fields `created_at`, `updated_at`. for custom fields use `timestamp()->nullable();`

Comment: But what if I don't want these timestamps to be nullable? If I want them to be set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for example.

Comment: You can use one as current, but I don't see why would you use two as current

Comment: I don't know, I find it strange that for example INT fields do not have to have a default value, but it is mandatory for timestamps.

Comment: The very first non-null field will be set to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default. I suppose everything should have a default value if not nullable.

Comment: I posted a new answer because I didn't know if you would be OK if I edited your answer as there might be mistakes.

Comment: The problem can arise if your DB-scheme is not english but, let's say, spanish... from a consistency point of view you'd like to have every column in the same language, so if you want to have a column named: 'creado' instead of 'created_at', laravel allows to define that in the model, but as we also see, the migration file does not recognize that... I am having the same issue, trying to use consistently spanish column names, but this date issue makes me doubt, whether to revert all created/odified columns to english, just to have no problem with this nullable() issue

Answer (score 2):

You can make one of the two timestamps nullable by using

```
timestamp()->nullable();
```

using your example, you would use:

```
$table->timestamp('timestamp2')->nullable();
```

Also laravel has built in timestamps by using

```
$table->timestamps();
```

which would automatically handle updated_at and created_at timestamping for you

Comment: I know for `timestamps()`, I just wanted to make my example simple.