# How do I fix "Invalid default value" error in Laravel when creating a migration script with two timestamps?

Tags: mysql, laravel

If I run this in a migration script, there are no issues:

```
Schema::create('cancel_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->timestamp('date')->index();
});
```

But the moment I add another timestamp:

```
Schema::create('cancel_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->timestamp('date')->index();
  $table->timestamp('created_at')->index();
});
```

Now I get this error:

```
QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

I can see the sql being generated as:

```
create table `cancel_requests` 
  (
    `id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
    `date` timestamp not null, 
    `created_at` timestamp not null
  ) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is failing when the "date" field has no issue and the sql being generated does not look incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You can just write `$table->timestamps();` at the end of `create` like:

```
Schema::create('cancel_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->timestamp('date')->index();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

It will create you `created_at` and `updated_at` fields with desired value.

[Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156519/eloquent-invalid-default-value-with-timestamps)

You have to define default value for `created_at` column in your situation like:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent()->index();
```

or

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))->index();
```

Comment: Thanks! That does solve it but it doesn't really answer my question. I want to know WHY my code fails, not how to make it work.